# Environment variables for OneDrive synchronisation folders

Tags: onedrive, microsoft-teams

This question relates to using Microsoft Teams and OneDrive.

The `%OneDrive%` environment variable can stand in for the local folder being used for personal OneDrive storage (e.g., `'C:\OneDrive - MyCompany' = %OneDrive%`, if typed into Windows explorer).

Is there an environment variable that can stand in for a synced folder, to facilitate sharing links on Teams chat? E.g., I'm hoping to pass a quick link to a coworker in the form:

`%OneDrive environment variable%\directory1\file.xyz`

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to accomplish and not ask about how to implement the solution you have come up with for the yet unspecified task. Users can’t access files in another user’s profile folder. Whatever it is you are trying to do, there is a misunderstanding and it’s not right.

Comment: Sure. Question has now been edited.

Comment: In a LAN, use `\\computer\share\file`. On the Internet, forget it.

Comment: I think you are expecting OneDrive to do something it wasn’t designed for. OneDrive shouldn’t play any role in sharing files on a LAN, unless it’s a sharepojnt site acting as a central repository for distributed workers. It’s still unclear if you just want files shared between users on the same computer or across a broader system and what that system is.

Comment: @Appleoddity There is now (since ~2020) a feature that lets you create shortcuts in OneDrive that point to a Sharepoint Document Library - so a path of the following %OneDriveCommercial\<mysharepoint-shortcut> is a valid solution.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The answer is to use `%OneDriveCommercial%` as the generic prefix to share paths among people using the same corporate OneDrive, e.g.,

```
%OneDriveCommercial%\directory1\file.xyz
```

For personal OneDrive, use `%OneDriveConsumer%`. If you have only one OneDrive client on your computer, `%OneDrive%` does the job.

Comment: So, on a PC with both a personal and work OneDrives; it appears that:

1. %OneDrive% sends to my work drive
2. %OneDriveCommercial% also goes to my work drive

Is there a variable for personal drive?

Thanks,
T

Comment: OneDriveConsumer=C:\Users\my_username\OneDrive works...

Comment: Is this different in Windows 11? At least on my machine, %OneDriveConsumer% does not work.

Comment: Both work on my Win 11 machine...